# get current date from [NSDate date] but set the time to 10:00 am

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsdate

How can I reset the current date retrieved from [NSDate date] but then change the time to 10:00 in the morning.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

As with all date manipulation you have to use [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents) and [NSCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar)

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:now];
[components setHour:10];
NSDate *today10am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

in iOS8 Apple introduced a convenience method that saves a few lines of code:

```
NSDate *d = [calendar dateBySettingHour:10 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

Swift:

```
let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let now: NSDate! = NSDate()

let date10h = calendar.dateBySettingHour(10, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchFirst)!
```

Comment: Why don't you use [NSCalendar currentCalendar] ? It would make code more universal.

Comment: Please note that NSYearCalendarUnit, NSMonthCalendarUnit and NSDayCalendarUnit are deprecated. Instead please use NSCalendarUnitYear, NSCalendarUnitMonth and NSCalendarUnitDay. Otherwise we may get some garbage date value.

Comment: [More information and examples on the new iOS 8 `NSCalendar` APIs](http://pivotallabs.com/?p=32104).

Comment: Heads up: This didn't work for me until I set the calendar's locale and the timezone.

Comment: @kraftydevil Can you please tell, how you provided locale and timezone?

Answer (score 4):

this `nsdate` used different format:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];

NSDateFormatter *inFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];

NSDate *parsed = [inFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: You didn't actually answer the question, but I found it very useful anyway: thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setHour:10];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
[comps release];
```

Not tested in xcode though :)

Comment: That won't work. You are adding 10 hours to the current date and time, not setting the time to 10:00.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, the answer of @flucchtpunkt seems correct

Answer (score 1):

I just set the timezone with Matthias Bauch answer And it worked for me. else it was adding 18:30 min more.

```
let cal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
cal.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
let newDate: NSDate = cal.dateBySettingHour(1, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions())!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for any minute / hour / period (aka am/pm) combination:

```
- (NSDate *)todayModifiedWithHours:(NSString *)hours
                           minutes:(NSString *)minutes
                         andPeriod:(NSString *)period
{
    NSDate *todayModified = NSDate.date;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:todayModified];

    [components setMinute:minutes.intValue];

    int hour = 0;

    if ([period.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"AM"]) {

        if (hours.intValue == 12) {
            hour = 0;
        }
        else {
            hour = hours.intValue;
        }
    }
    else if ([period.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"PM"]) {

        if (hours.intValue != 12) {
            hour = hours.intValue + 12;
        }
        else {
            hour = 12;
        }
    }
    [components setHour:hour];

    todayModified = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    return todayModified;
}
```

**Requested Example:**

```
NSDate *todayAt10AM = [self todayModifiedWithHours:@"10"
                                           minutes:@"00"
                                         andPeriod:@"am"];
```