# Programmatically getting the date "next Sunday at 5PM"

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

**Edited 07/08/13: Apple has an excellent set of WWDC videos that really helped me understand the various date and time classes in Objective-C, and how to correctly perform time calculations/manipulations with them.**

**"Solutions to Common Date and Time Challenges" ([HD video](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/227xax5xif2s7s531dsmfs1afo2/227/227-HD.mov?dl=1), [SD video](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/227xax5xif2s7s531dsmfs1afo2/227/227-SD.mov?dl=1), [slides (PDF)](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/227xax5xif2s7s531dsmfs1afo2/227/227.pdf?dl=1)) (WWDC 2013)**
**"Performing Calendar Calculations" ([SD video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/performing-calendar-calculations.html#performing-calendar-calculations), [slides (PDF)](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/117performing_calendar_calculations.pdf)) (WWDC 2011)**

**Note: links require a free Apple Developer membership.**

I'm writing an app for a friend's podcast. She broadcasts her show live every Sunday at 5PM, and I would like to write some code in my app to optionally schedule a local notification for that time, so that the user is reminded of when the next live show is.  How would I go about getting an NSDate object that represents "the next Sunday, at 5 PM Pacific time."  (obviously this would have to be converted into whatever timezone the user is using)

Comment: Awesome linking and update. Good on you !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First get the current day of the week:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:now];
NSInteger weekday = [dateComponents weekday];
```

The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) define a weekday as:

> Weekday units are the numbers 1 through n, where n is the number of
>   days in the week. For example, in the Gregorian calendar, n is 7 and
>   Sunday is represented by 1.

Next figure out how many days to add to get to the next sunday at 5:

```
NSDate *nextSunday = nil;
if (weekday == 1 && [dateComponents hour] < 5) {
    // The next Sunday is today
    nextSunday = now;
} else {
    NSInteger daysTillNextSunday = 8 - weekday;
    int secondsInDay = 86400; // 24 * 60 * 60  
    nextSunday = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInDay * daysTillNextSunday];
 }
```

To get it at 5:00 you can just change the hour and minute on `nextSunday` to 5:00. Take a look at [get current date from [NSDate date] but set the time to 10:00 am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611632/get-current-date-from-nsdate-date-but-set-the-time-to-1000-am)

Comment: There's a subtle bug in this code. The `calendar` implicitly uses the current locale. If that means for example a New Zealand time zone it differs substantially differs from Pacific time. The result might be that the code calculates the next Sunday in 6 or 7 days when the next *Californian* Sunday-at-5 is only a couple of hours ahead.

Comment: Also, the code to calculate `nextSunday` breaks when there's a daylight change in that period.