# (iOS, Objective-C) Handling different time zones when calculating dates/times

Tags: objective-c, timezone, nsdate

**Edited 07/08/13: Apple has an excellent set of WWDC videos that really helped me understand the various date and time classes in Objective-C, and how to correctly perform time calculations/manipulations with them.**

**"Solutions to Common Date and Time Challenges" ([HD video](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/227xax5xif2s7s531dsmfs1afo2/227/227-HD.mov?dl=1), [SD video](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/227xax5xif2s7s531dsmfs1afo2/227/227-SD.mov?dl=1), [slides (PDF)](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/227xax5xif2s7s531dsmfs1afo2/227/227.pdf?dl=1)) (WWDC 2013)**
**"Performing Calendar Calculations" ([SD video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/performing-calendar-calculations.html#performing-calendar-calculations), [slides (PDF)](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/117performing_calendar_calculations.pdf)) (WWDC 2011)**

**Note: links require a free Apple Developer membership.**

In [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829705/programmatically-getting-the-date-next-sunday-at-5pm), I asked how I might go about calculating a certain date and time ("next Sunday at 5 PM").  Thanks to the answers I got, I came up with the following code:

```
 - (NSDate *) toPacificTime
 {
     NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"];
     NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate: self];
     return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: seconds sinceDate: self];
 }

 - (void)handleLiveShowReminders
 {
    NSDate *gmtNow = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *now = [gmtNow toPacificTime];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"]];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    NSInteger weekday = [dateComponents weekday];

    NSInteger daysTillNextSunday = 8 - weekday;

    int secondsInDay = 86400; // 24 * 60 * 60
    NSDate *nextSunday = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInDay * daysTillNextSunday];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:nextSunday];
    [components setHour:17];
    [components setMinute:00];
    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"]];
    NSDate *nextSunday5PM = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    warningInterval = -300;    // we want the notification to fire 5 minutes beforehand

    NSDate *alertDate = [nextSunday5PM dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)warningInterval];

    UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (notifyAlarm)
    {
        notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertDate;
        notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"];    
        notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        notifyAlarm.soundName = @"alert.aif";
        notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"LIVE SHOW REMINDER: The live show is about to start!";

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    }
 }
```

The problem is that, although this code works for me, it's not working for anyone who's not in the PST timezone, as can be seen by this debug output I received from a user in EST:

```
number of notifications = 1

Notification #1
===================
Body: LIVE SHOW REMINDER: The live show is about to start!
Details: <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x1d5f2200>
{fire date = Sunday, December 9, 2012, 4:30:00 PM Pacific Standard Time,
time zone = America/Los_Angeles (PST) offset -28800,
repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit
repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount,
next fire date = Sunday, December 9, 2012, 4:30:00 PM Eastern Standard Time,
user info = (null)}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: hey, any chance you were able to figure out the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

One problem with your logic, just adding 86,400 to your time interval might not be what you want. If for example, the user experiences daylight-savings, then you will be off by an hour, or even a day if it happens near midnight. A better method is to ask the NSCalendar for the result, which takes into account the users local time zone.

```
NSDate *start = yourDate;
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [NSDateComponents new];
[oneDay setDay:1];

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *end = [cal dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:start options:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

And NSDate is relative to UTC/GMT.  When you "adjust" if for Pacific time you create utter confusion.